# Is there a solution to have a default value for a struct

Tags: swift

I explain myself:

I extend UIColor like that:

```
struct MyColors {

        struct blue {
            static let light = UIColor(netHex: 0x6ABB72)
            static let normal = UIColor(netHex: 0x6ABB72)
            static let dark = UIColor(netHex: 0x6ABB72)
        }
    }
```

is there a solution to do UIColor.MyColors.blue for UIColor.MyColors.blue.normal ?

Comment: Where is this initializer UIColor(netxHex:) defined ? As you have a struct, you need to tell which constant to use when you call MyColors.blue. You could define a func blue() in struct MyColors that return MyColors.blue.normal and then call UIColor.MyColors.blue(). Or define static const (with different name, I call it blueX) static let blueX = MyColors.blue.normal. and call it as UIColor.MyColors.blueX. (of course adapt names to your convenience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to adapt your app for light- and darkmode you could even do the following:
Go to your Assets-Folder -> Click the plus button in the lower left corner -> Select 'New Color Set' -> Then go to the inspector and set the Appearances option to 'Any, Light, Dark' -> Set the color for each appearance.
You could then use the color like so:

`UIColor(named: <Name of your Color Set>)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I forgot this post.
But I discover the color assets and it's great ! ahaha

Answer (score 0):

To approximate what you want to do, consider using a function to return the color with a given shade, and then use default arguments, e.g.:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    enum MyColor {
        case blue

        enum Shade { case normal, light, dark }

        func shade(_ shade: Shade) -> UIColor {
            switch self {
            case .blue:
                switch shade {
                case .normal: return .init(netHex: 0x000099)
                case .light:  return .init(netHex: 0x0066cc)
                case .dark:   return .init(netHex: 0x000066)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static func my(_ color: MyColor, shade: MyColor.Shade = .normal) -> UIColor {
        return color.shade(shade)
    }
}
```

The syntax for use would be slightly different:

```swift
let myBlue = UIColor.my(.blue)
```

As bonus, you can add these to `MyColor`:

```swift
        var normal: UIColor { shade(.normal) }
        var light: UIColor { shade(.light) }
        var dark: UIColor { shade(.dark) }
```

Then you can do `UIColor.MyColor.blue.dark` like before.

*However*, I would instead suggest just adding the colors themselves as `UIColor` extensions:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    static let myBlue = UIColor(named: "blue")
    static let myLightBlue = UIColor(named: "lightBlue")
    static let myDarkBlue = UIColor(named: "darkBlue")
}
```

This even allows you to use shorthand like:

```swift
label.textColor = .myBlue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `UIColor` with a static property storing the type `MyColors`.

```
extension UIColor {
    static let myColors = MyColors.self
}
```

and then access the colors like

```
UIColor.myColors.blue.light
```

Or you can actually declare `MyColors` in the `UIColor` namespace like

```
extension UIColor {
    struct MyColors {
        struct Blue {
            static let light = ...
```

And then access them like this: `UIColor.MyColors.Blue.light`

Comment: Thanks I did that before but now I'm using Color Set and it's better for dark mode, but thanks 